# BQ Aquaris lock screen not working

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I got my new ubuntu phone, an aquaris 4.5 and at the beginning everything was fine. At some point however the lock screen started not working anymore. Essentially I can't swipe from right to left in order to unlock the phone, it just does not respond to any touch.
The way I have to unlock my phone and use it is actually swiping from left to right as I gave access to unity bar while locked so that it then prompts me to unlock the phone. I'm not sure why it doe snot repsond anymore......however it is quite dangerous, if I don;t allow the menu when phone is locked...I can't unlock it at all

Answer (score 1):

That seems like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1435988 you might want to comment on that bug/confirm it/subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Same here; BQ Aquaris E5 OTA-12.

The only solution in my case was to keep pushed power button until it turned off (about 10 secs); then I restarted it and everything was working again.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having this issue once in the past, but a reboot also worked for me too. However, before the reboot the way I was able to get back into my phone was to drag down the top bar and click on something like Mobile Settings that would prompt me for my password before taking me into my system. I had to use this as I had not enabled the Unity bar on screen lock. I had this once and have not seen it again after the reboot.